# Linq to entities query not working

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
if (entities.User.Count(u => u.Id == ownerUserId && u.GroupId == null) == 0)
```

I want to check if User with Id == ownerUserId has its GroupId == null, but it doesn't work.

Table:

```
User
----------------------------------------
Id                  | PK Not Null
GroupId             | FK to Group Table. CAN BE NULL.
...
```

I want to check if User with `Id == ownerId` has `GroupId == null`

Do you know why?

Comment: Doesn't work is not clear description of your problem. What does it mean?

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: But it still doesn't explain what doesn't work. Is it returning incorrect result or throwing exception?

Comment: It returns an incorrect result.

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!!!! -1 vote and nobody tells why!! Thanks. I will learn a lot with this vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the if condition to be true in the case you mentioned, you would need to check for greater than 0, rather than equal to 0.